# MySQL SELECT WHERE id = N not matching exactly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a simple select like this:

```
$productId = '241';

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->execute([ $productId ]);
$product = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

It works, but if I change productId to this:

```
$productId = '241FJKSDFJKDSJKF';
```

it still brings me the product, whereas it should, since it doesn't match. Why is this happening?

I think I get it, `id` is primary key, auto increment so non numerical characters are being ignored, still I don't want this behaviour, is there any way to change it?

Comment: Since the ID most likely is a column with integer as type, the string `241FJKSDFJKDSJKF` will be cast into: `241`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson any way of preventing this?

Comment: Screen your inputs and reject non-numerical data?

Comment: Not sure, but you could try and set the parameter with a type. Instead of binding the params by passing them to `execute()` (where all of them are treated as strings), try adding them with [bindParam()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and explicitly set the param as integer in the third argument.

Comment: *I don't want this behaviour*, then validate input is a number.